# Apache HTACCESS: Deliver another file than requested in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've got a pretty complex and big Wordpress site which is using a lot of plugins. Even with all sorts of optimization, load times on the home-page are pretty bad. What I've done is to automatically cache the entire home-page in an .html-File every 15 minutes.

Now if the user searches for "my-website.com" or "my-website.com/index.php" in his browser, I want the webserver to deliver the "index.html"-page **without a redirect**. Is there a way to achieve this? - Please keep in mind, that only the home-page should be affected - all the other sites (like "my-website.com/blog" for instance) should still be delivered via Wordpress.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could modify the rewrite rule so if no page is requested the index.html is served. Currently wodpress sends everything to a controller.

Comment: Well you can check for the existence of a file using a `RewriteCond`, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `DirectoryIndex` . Add the following directive to your htaccess file or replace the existing one with this :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

To show the `index.html` file content for `index.php` add the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.html [L]
```